# Is there any other way to use dependency .aar in Android projects?

Tags: android, git, maven, gradle

**What i did:**

I have a library module(.aar) depends on many external .aar libraries

So, I pushed the .aar libraries to remote repository(**bintray**-> maven)*(With
reference link - https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en )*

Library module working

**What i need to know:**

Bintray is free only for *public* Git repositories,when i use "*private*",its costly.

*Is there any way to use dependency .aar in Android projects,with private access?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To host private aar files you have two options:
1) Use a **private repository hosting service** such as [Bintray](https://bintray.com) or [JitPack](https://jitpack.io) premium.
2) Setup your **own server** and host aar files there. Use Jfrog Artifactory [link](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/) and host it in a server of your choice. Artifactory is free to use and has many features including private access and user management.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,Whether "Artifactory"(2nd option) is completely opensource?

Comment: @Shahbaz Ahmed Will this support Continous integration and deployment?

Comment: @Shahbaz Ahmed  can you suggest any documentation  or step(link) to make the effort quick?

Comment: @Cibin William Artifactory has both open source and premium versions. Check out this link for further info : https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-setup-private-maven-repository/en. Also if it helped mark this as accepted answer.

Comment: @SKK yes it also supports Continuation integration by hooking up with other CI tools like Jenkins, Bamboo, etc.

Comment: @ShahbazAhmed great. Thank you for the information.

Comment: @ShahbazAhmed In the link " https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/ " ."JFrog OSS"  Feature/Service missing many features in "opensource" when compared to "pro" and "SaaS" version.Whether it affect the Continuous integration ?

Comment: Which other solutions you know to host aar files? It seems Jfrog will be shut down, and so all its hosting services... Is it possible to even have my own host, and have a dependency to it?